# cannot import name 'Axes3d'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use miniconda, python 3.6.4, win 10 pro, the problem is[image]

I want to plot a 3d figure, how to continue?

Comment: Please, share your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct import statement is:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

The D is capital.

Comment: Thank you, I think my code autocompletion is stupid.

Comment: happy to help :)